# Is there any approach to inject or ignore global variables when babel compiling?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs

There is a `__DEVTOOLS__` global variable in my source code. And normally I use webpack DefinePlugin to define it as boolean value.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEVTOOLS__: true
})
```

But in my mocha test I only want to use `babel/register` and don't want to use wepack in my test. Is there any approach to inject global variables just like webpack DefinePlugin or at least ignore the global variables when it compile?

Answer (score 8):

I recently ran into this issue and adding `global.__DEVTOOLS__ = true;` to a `before` block, or any where in a test, did not work for me. I ended up solving this be creating a separate script that is passed to mocha cli via the `--require` flag.

```
// config/mocha-setup.js

require('babel-register');

global.__DEVTOOLS__ = true;
```

Then configure the test command:

```
// package.json

scripts: {
  test: mocha --require ./config/mocha-setup
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue of having a global variable in my non-test code!

Answer (score 6):

With Mocha you can assign properties to the `global` object, which I think will achieve what you want:

```
global.__DEVTOOLS__ = true;
```

You can put this wherever you want, e.g. a `before` block, but if you already have a `helper.js` or `setup.js` file that you load before your tests, that would be a good place to put it.

Comment: but when using `mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive`, it seems will do compile first, so I will failed before run tests.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. If you need a global variable named `__DEVTOOLS__` in your tests, then setting `global.__DEVTOOLS__` will achieve that as long as it's done before your tests run—regardless of whether it happens before or after compilation.

Comment: I got `ReferenceError: __DEVTOOLS__ is not defined` before any test code running. babel compiling is earlier than mocha running, so I should find a place to inject `global.__DEVTOOLS__ = true;` before babel compiling.

Comment: Where is the error coming from? If you're getting `__DEVTOOLS__ is not defined` before Mocha runs, then it means some code is trying to access `__DEVTOOLS__` before Mocha runs.

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for using the Webpack DefinePlugin. I have a "/src/actions/index.js" module that used the DefinePlugin for a __BASE__ URL for my application's various environments. Setting 'global.__BASE__' inside my "test/test_helper.js" resolved my issue of __BASE__ being otherwise undefined.